# SSH configuration problems with Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, ssh, configuration

I'm stumped, after reading online for a bit. I'm trying to enable agentforwarding on all hosts (I know this isn't recommended, but I know the servers I'll be touching from this box) and to disable password authentication.

```
In my ~/.ssh/config file I have this:

PasswordAuthentication no

host *
        ForwardAgent yes
```

I have run `chmod 600` on my *config* file, eventually I did it recursively from the `.ssh` folder. Nothing worked, I tried restarting ssh on my box `/etc/init.d/ssh restart`

I tried updating the paremeters in `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`, here is a snippet:

```
Host *
   ForwardAgent yes 
#   ForwardX11 no
#   ForwardX11Trusted yes
#   RhostsRSAAuthentication no
#   RSAAuthentication yes
   PasswordAuthentication no
```

Perhaps I'm searching with the wrong terminology, or I'm missing something that is right in front of me? My end game is to

1. not be prompted for a password every time I connect to a server
2. be able to ssh into a host & then into another from that machine with my same key

Comment: Possibly this thread can help you:

[SSH without pwd][1]


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/449364/what-does-without-password-mean-in-sshd-config-file

Comment: Thank you--but this isn't quite it. I'm still searching as well.

Answer (score 1):

Flipping these entries around *seems* to do the trick.

```
host *
        PasswordAuthentication no
        ForwardAgent yes
```

this was in my `~/.ssh/config`  file.