# PermitRootLogin without-password not working

Tags: 14.04, ssh, root

I followed the step six at https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-ssh-keys-with-digitalocean-droplets but I still get a password prompt when I try to connect to the server using ssh from other machines that don't have the private key.

Troubleshooting ideas? Thanks

Comment: The guide only denys root login via password. Are you using antother user to log in?

Comment: I'm trying "ssh root@myipaddress" which gives "root@myipaddress's password:"

Comment: Have you restarted the ssh server after chaning the config? If so, please edit your post with your `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.

Comment: I ran "service ssh restart" but get the same problem. `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` is at http://pastebin.com/zCwbDTAU

Comment: Config looks fine. If the server restart was successfull please edit the question with the output from `ssh -vv root@server`. Make sure to replace the IP in the output.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is normal behaviour. You will be prompted for a password, but if `PermitRootLogin without-password` is set, then  no password will work. If you don't want to be prompted for a password at all, then set in your [`sshd_config`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/sshd_config):

```
PasswordAuthentication no
```

If you only want to deny it for `root`, try:

```
Match User root
    PasswordAuthentication no
```

Comment: `Match User root
    PasswordAuthentication no` seems to have worked :) Can anyone confirm you should still see the prompt if you use `without-password` (I'm hosting my machine with digital ocean and don't really want them to e-mail me the password for me to try this theory out)?

Comment: @user3553107 Anyone other than me?

Comment: After the amount of dubious comments on the original guide I posted it's always good to check ;) If you had a man page etc stating the expected behaviour that would be great

Comment: @user3553107 The manpage doesn't mention the expected behaviour, but [this question](http://askubuntu.com/q/449364/158442) shows imilar behaviour.

Comment: @user3553107: check the comment above `UsePAM yes` in your `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`