# Can't change root password, passwd doesn't do anything

Tags: server, permissions, login, password, passwd

I just got a dedicated server with ubuntu 14.04 on it. I haven't received root details in my server info email, but instead for a different user. So I wanted root access and tried to change the password.

I tried:

```
sudo -i
passwd
```

and

```
sudo passwd root
```

And I entered my new root password, but when I try to login as root I still get denied access.

If anybody can help me it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Do you get any error messages when you run `sudo passwd root`?

Comment: Check the output of `sudo getent shadow root | cut -d: -f2` ..does it start with `$` or something else like `!` ....DON'T POST THE OUTPUT HERE..

Comment: @Arronical No I don't get any errors, it just asks me to enter the new password twice

Comment: It's probably because you are trying to log in as root *via ssh* using the password, and that is disabled for security reasons - just don't do it. Either stick to sudo or - if you really must log in directly as root - set up key-based authentication.

Comment: @heemayl Yeah it starts with a $, what do I do to fix that?

Comment: That means the password is correctly saved and root account is activated..how are you logging into the root account i mean the procedure ?

Comment: @heemayl logging in with SSH via PuTTY

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default in Ubuntu the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file of the `openssh-server` has the following line:

```
PermitRootLogin without-password
```

this prevents to login into the ssh-server as `root` using password which is for security reasons, you can use key based authentication (and any other not using password) mechanism to login as `root` directly.

So you have two options:

- First the bad option, avoid this one. Make the line of `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` as:

  ```
    PermitRootLogin password
  ```
- The good option is to login as another user who has access to the server, then switch to the root account by:

  ```
    su - root  ## Will need root's password.
  ```

or

```
    sudo su -  ## Will need calling user's password. The calling user needs to be able to use sudo.
```

Comment: Good advice, I always edit the `PermitRootLogin` line to `no` to be extra safe!

Comment: I wanted to do this just temporarily, in order to change a different account. However, `PermitRootLogin password` is invalid configuration - the correct way would be `PermitRootLogin yes` (which is the default, so just commenting out the line entirely works too). See https://askubuntu.com/a/449372/18112