# How do people transfer files (e.g. website files) if they have root disabled?

Tags: server, permissions, ftp, filezilla, upload

So I have root logins disabled and I log in through a... sudo-user? (whatever you call "another user that isn't root but was added via `adduser username sudo`).

However I installed Filezilla because I want to be able to write/modify my website files locally and then upload them to the `public_html` folder on the server.

However, even with my password and all, Filezilla tells me that I don't have the right permissions to actually make any changes (I can't upload files to the designated folders, I can only see the folder / file structure of the server / account).

So how else can I do this kind of file uploading?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two general options:

1. [How to avoid using sudo when working in /var/www?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/46331/how-to-avoid-using-sudo-when-working-in-var-www)
2. Allow root logins but mitigate the risk

   - Use keys
   - Disable password authentication
   - Use iptables or fail2ban to block brute force attacks

These iptables rules mitigate brute force attacks

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -m tcp -m state --state NEW -m recent --set --name SSH --rsource

iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -m recent --update --seconds 600 --hitcount 20 --rttl --name SSH --rsource -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
```

See:
http://bodhizazen.com/Tutorials/SSH_keys

and

[What does 'without password' mean in sshd_config file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/449364/what-does-without-password-mean-in-sshd-config-file)

and

http://bodhizazen.com/Tutorials/iptables

Comment: Can I keep password authentication (e.g. permitrootaccess set to on) but block brute-force attacks? (and how are they mitigated/blocked exactly?)

Comment: Even if I disable password authentication, doesn't that then mean the weakness moves to a new goalpost: Someone can try to take my local machine (or get access to it) and take the key file and use that to get root access?

Comment: key still requires a password

Comment: I thought that was not mandatory technically?

Comment: No you can skip a password if you wish but I do not advise it without using forced commands